# SUMPRODUCT( SUMIF() ) - How does this work?

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula

### Part 1:

I was able to construct a formula that does exactly what I want (from some examples), but yet, I'm unable to figure out how exactly it works. I have, starting with cell A1:

```
Price   $
table   20
chair   10

Invoice Quantity
table   17
chair   1
chair   2
table   3
```

What I want is the final total (430) for the invoice which is computed as Quantity*Price for each item (17*20 + 1*10 + 2*10 + 3*20). the following formula correctly does this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B6:B9,SUMIF(A2:A3,A6:A9,B2:B3))
```

I understand the basics of SUMPRODUCT and SUMIF. But here, my argument for SUMIF's range is A2:A3, which makes me think the SUMIF would iterate through A2 and A3, and not through A8:A11 (which is the criteria). What gives?

**Edit: the unclear part is, what exactly does SUMIF do (what is its iteration pattern) when the first two arguments are of different dimensions (here, the range is 2 cells while the criteria is 4 cells). Also, what is the "output" of SUMIF? An array? Of what dimensions?**

### Part 2:

In addition, if I ignored the quantity and simply wanted to add 20 whenever I saw a table and 10 whenever I saw a chair, I figured I would do:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A3,A6:A9,B2:B3)
```

But that doesn't work, and I have to enclose it with a SUMPRODUCT() for it to work and correctly evaluate to 60. Enclosing it within a SUM doesn't work either (probably because the SUMIF doesn't return an array?) Why?

I've read a bunch of tutorials and still can't understand this, and would be most grateful for a clear, intuitive explanation for both these cases. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps a step-by-step explanation (in algorithm style) of what Excel does with my formulas above (or how it iterates through them) would be one way to show how this all works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SUMIF` can produce an array of results. If you take my formula
`=SUMIF(A6:A9,A2:A3,B6:B9)`
it says

For the criteria in A2 (ie table)
 - look at A6:A9
 - where table is matched, sum the corresponding value in B6:B9
 - returns 20 (ie 17 +0 +0 +3)
 - this is stored in the first position of the array

Then for the criteria in A3 (ie chair)
 - look at A6:A9
 - where table is matched, sum the corresponding value in B6:B9
 - returns 3 (ie 0 +1 +2 +0)
 - this is stored in the second position of the array

So the end array from the `SUMIF` is {20:3}

*You can see the array result by highlighting the SUMIF formula in Excel's formula bar and then pressing F9*

Then use `SUMPRODUCT` to multiple the count in the `SUMIF` by the $ values in B2:B3 to get total dollars

={20;3}*{20:10}
=20*20 + 3*10
= 430

**Part 1**
Rather than
`SUMIF(A2:A3,A6:A9,B2:B3)`
which produces a four element array of
={20;10;10;20}
*(corresponding to table;chair;chair;table)*

You should use
`SUMIF(A6:A9,A2:A3,B6:B9)`
which sums the values in B6:B9 against your two criteria in A2:A3 giving the desired result
={20;3}
*(corresponding to table;chair)*

and then use `SUMPRODUCT` to weight your array, ie
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A6:A9,A2:A3,B6:B9),B2:B3)` 
={20;3}*{20:10}
=430

**Part 2**
Use `COUNTIF` to return an array of the number of chairs and tables and then multiply by the vales using `SUMPRODUCT`
`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B3,COUNTIF(A6:A9,A2:A3))`
 ={20;10} * {2;2}
 =60

Comment: It helps to see another example, and thanks for that, but my solution works too: I was looking more for a direct explanation of *why* my solution (and, for that matter, your solution) works.

Comment: @redstreet hopefully this expansion helps

Comment: Great, I understand now. Thanks for the explanation and also for the F9 tip which is also very useful in understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you only have one minor mistake:

> probably because the SUMIF doesn't return an array?

SUMIF can work with arrays, thats why you formula **SUMPRODUCT( SUMIF() )** works in first place, to SUMIF show an array you have to select  a group of cells (like C6:C9) input the formula and use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER only. this generate an "array fomula", identified by curly brackets {} (those can only be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, no manualy) and show the array formula and results

Comment: Actually you can just use F9 on the SUMIF in the formula bar to see the array behind it.