# SUMPRODUCT vs SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to make an in-company guide to Excel (we're a small non-profit and sorely need some sort of baseline guide). However, I've gotten stuck trying to explain the differences between SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS.

My understanding is that SUMPRODUCT was used before Excel 2007 as a way to have multiple SUMIF criteria (among other things). Now that SUMIFS is available, is there any difference in the capacity of both formulas?

I've looked around a bit and found that SUMIFS tends to be faster, but that was it... Any insights and/or reading material is appreciated!

Comment: Part of the answer is here (see the 2 answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480017/sumproduct-sumif-how-does-this-work?rq=1

Comment: Excel 2010 has a [bug](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cda9fef8-8ad4-4d56-8939-49b1ae50c4e7/bug-in-excel-2010-sumif-sumifs-functions-edit-also-averageif-ifs?forum=excel) for SUMIFS() formula.

Comment: One advantage of SUMIFS is that it can handle text or an error by simply skiping these cells. But, while using SUMPRODUCT you will get an error message. (Which can also be an advantage sometimes :-))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT` can be used more flexibly than `SUMIFS` because you can modify the ranges with other functions in `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g. if you have a range of dates in `A2:A100` how can you sum the corresponding amounts in `B2:B100` for `December` dates (in any year)?

You can use this formula to get the answer

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A100)=12)+0,B2:B100)`

You can't do that easily with `SUMIFS`, although if the dates are all in one year you can just use the start and end points of the range as the criterion in `SUMIFS`, e.g. for December 2014 only:

`=SUMIFS(B2:B100,A2:A100,">="&DATE(2014,12,1),A2:A100,"<"&DATE(2015,1,1))`

`SUMPRODUCT` can also be used to reference data in **closed** workbooks, `SUMIFS` can't do that  - see here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260415

...but in general `SUMIFS` is significantly quicker, I've seen a `5x` figure quoted but I haven't verified that.

For multiple interesting uses of `SUMPRODUCT` see this article by MS Excel MVP `Bob Philips`

http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html

Comment: Barry, I've validated SUMIFS being 3X faster using Charles William's FastExcel. Significant for big models.

Comment: `SUMIFS` over 5x faster than `SUMPRODUCT` per test here: https://exceloffthegrid.com/optimize-formula-calculation-speed-part-8-sum-with-multiple-criteria/

Answer (score 6):

1. `SUMIFS` typically works within **30%** of a similar `SUMPRODUCT` formula's calculation load.
2. `SUMIFS` can use full column references (e.g. A:A instead of A2:A999) without compromising calculation lag the way `SUMPRODUCT` does by only actually calculating the *used range*.
3. `SUMIFS` happily skips over text values in a column that would create an error with `SUMPRODUCT` in a mathematical operation.
4. While `SUMPRODUCT` does provide some functionality that `SUMIFS` misses (the `OR` functionality mentioned above being one of the most commonly required), the newer `SUMIFS` is by far the preferred method whenever it can be used.

Answer (score 5):

`SUMPRODUCT` can actually sum the products from multiple arrays, `SUMIFS` will sum only values from a single range.

e.g. for input data

```
10    1
20    2
30    3
```

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3, B1:B3)` => 10*1 + 20*2 + 30*3 = 140

Answer (score 5):

`SUMPRODUCT` works like array formulas. That gives you a lot more flexibility than SUMIF.  Here's an example where you can have an OR (+ in summproduct)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Marketing")*((B1:B10="North")+(B1:B10="South"))*(C1:C10))
```

That will sum everything that has marketing in A and either North or South in B.

Here's an example that uses a function on a range

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A3:A7)=2014)*(B3:B7=1)*(C3:C7))
```

That will sum everything where the year of the date in col A is 2014 and col B is 1.

Comment: The particular circumstance you address in your first formula may also be derived with `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Marketing")*(B1:B10={"North","South"})*(C1:C10))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"marketing",B:B, {"north","south"}))`. Half of this and half of that; same difference.

Comment: That's nice. Yours is a little easier to read, I think, rather than parsing the parentheses.