# Excel conditional SUMPRODUCT / SUMIFS / Array Formula for optional dimension

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a sheet of `data` with multiple dimensions like this:

```
    A         B           C        D           E  
1   COUNTRY   FLAVOUR     SIZE     DATE        SALES ($)
2   Japan     Strawberry  100ml    10/12/14    100
3   Japan     Banana      100ml    10/03/15    100
4   China     Orange      200ml    14/04/15    30
5   France    Strawberry  200ml    11/04/15    400
6   UK                    200ml    23/04/15    250
7   ....
```

I want to aggregate this data over a date range, where the `summary` sheet has each dimension (country & flavour), and if I do not specify a dimension it sums all rows for that dimension.

```
    A         B           C
1   COUNTRY   FLAVOUR     SALES TOTAL
2   Japan     Strawberry  100
3   Japan                 200
4             Strawberry  500
```

I can do this if all the dimensions are present (i.e. row 2 above) using a SUMPRODUCT or SUMIFS:

`=SUMPRODUCT((data!A$2:A$100=A1)*(data!B$2:B$100=B1)*(data!D$2:D$100>[start_date]*(data!D$2:D$100<[end_date])*(data!E$2:E$100))`

However I have not been able to figure out how to include all rows for a dimension if that input cell is empty (e.g. row 3 above).  I tried:

- Adding an IF statement or OR statement within the criteria (e.g. `OR(data!A$2:A$100=A1,isblank(A1))`).
- Using a `+` in a SUMPRODUCT as an OR statement, (per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536131/1450420)

One solution is to have different branches of the formula depending on which summary dimensions are present, but that would quickly get out of control if I extend this same behaviour to further dimensions like `Size`.

Any help appreciated!

(I'm running Excel Mac 2011).

**EDIT**

Per @BrakNicku's comment one of the formulas I tried was `=SUMPRODUCT(((data!A$2:A$100=A2)+ISBLANK(A2))*((data!B$2:B$100=B2)+ISBLANK(B2))*(data!E$2:E$100))`

The reason this doesn't work is that sometimes my data has blank attributes (edited above). For some reason this formula double-counts rows where the attribute present matches (e.g. `data!A6`) but the other attribute is missing (e.g. `data!B6`).

**EDIT 2**

I can see why this double-counting is happening, because the `+` is summing the match because `data!A$2:A$100=A2` (they match because they are both blank) and the match because `ISBLANK(A2)` (it is indeed blank).  The question would remain how to achieve this without double counting.  If needed a workaround could be to fill all blank cells on my data with some placeholder value.

Comment: Using `+ISBLANK(...)`  for A and B columns should give correct results. What is exactly the formula you tried?

Comment: @BrakNicku thanks for your help.  I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for double-counting values is here:

```
((data!A$2:A$100=A2)+ISBLANK(A2))
```

If a cell in A column is blank, both parts of this sum are equal 1. To get rid of this problem you can change it to:

```
(((data!A$2:A$100=A2)+ISBLANK(A2))>0)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Much appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I only included the first two, I left the dates out):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((((Data!$A$2:$A$5=A2)+(A2=""))>0)*(((Data!$B$2:$B$5=B2)+(B2=""))>0)*(Data!$E$2:$E$5))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]