# Trying to SUM INDEX but its not MATCHing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to match Note column with sum but currently, it's giving me the monthly total.

Current formula: `=SUM(INDEX(C4:C47,0,MATCH($A$83,D4:D47,0)))`

Sum should be 36.96 (18.99 + (5.99 x 3)).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the sum be 30.97 (5.99 + 5.99 + 18.99)?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Good catch. There's one more 5.99 not in the screenshot.

Comment: Isn;t that what SUMIF is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula -

`=SUMPRODUCT(($D$4:$D$47 = A83)*$C$4:$C$47)`

Comment: this is not the purpose of `SUMPRODUCT`, instead `SUMIF` it's been made for this

Comment: `SUMIF` is obviously good.. no doubt.. but `SUMPRODUCT` is also powerful. I use it more than `SUMIF` in my daily routine.

Comment: There are two arguments for SUMIF over SUMPRODUCT: 1. Quicker, it is not as overhead intensive. 2.Less typing.  Where SUMIF does not work then I always fall back to SUMPRODUCT.  But where it does work, it is saves time in those two ways.  Your formula is not bad, but if the user had 10,000 rows, it would be slower than SUMIF.

Comment: Yes, `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` are significantly faster than `SUMPRODUCT`. They are really good. Your answer is perfect. But `SUMPRODUCT` is also not bad. You can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536083. It's more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

SUMIF is not an array formula:

```
=SUMIF($D$4:$D$47,A83,$C$4:$C$47)
```